# Dropzone init() is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am customizing the **dropzone.js**

My layout is:

[image]

My HTML Content is:

```
<form action="/Drag/SaveUploadedData/" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dropzoneForm">
<div class="dropzone" id="mydropzone"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;">
    <ul style="color:red;">
        <li style="list-style-type:square;">
            Invalid file name/type
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type='file' id='fileUpload' style='opacity:0;' multiple onchange="javascript: addFilesToDropzone();" />
```

I am using a link as a fileUpload called "***Browse***"

On clicking this, will open a open file dialog and we will choose the file.

I have written in `onchange="javascript: addFilesToDropzone();"` event of `#fileUpload`.
This will trigger the following function,

```
function addFilesToDropzone()
{
    document.getElementById('mydropzone').files = document.getElementById('fileUpload').files;

    Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
        init: function () {
            //var dropZone = this;
            if (document.getElementById('mydropzone').files.length > 0) {
                alert();
                $.each(files, function (index, item) {
                    this.emit('addedfile', 'uploading');
                });
            }

        }
    };
}
```

My problem is, it is not executing the `Dropzone.options.mydropzone` line and hence it is not executing the `init()`.

I got the files from `#fileUpload` input, but it is not executing the `init()` in order to call the `addedfile` method in **dropzone.js**

Why it is happening? and how to solve this problem?.

Comment: I don't think it will affect your problem, but the "javascript:" is no longer considered necessary.

Comment: I am not familiar with dropzone and since there is no fiddle I can't say for sure, however.. I don't see anywhere in your code that you are actually calling the init function. the `Dropzone.options.mydropzone` is just a javascript object you don't actually "see" it executed.

Comment: I am calling init : function(){} inside the Dropzone.options.mydropzone. But it is not calling. Thats the problem @Saar

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying. Could you please explain me clearly? @ParrisVarney

Comment: you are not calling init at any point in this code, you are just defining it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in this code you are defining a javascript object named mydropzone inside of the object options which is inside of the object Dropzone.

inside of the object mydropzone you defined a function called init.

```
 Dropzone.options.mydropzone = {
        init: function () {
            //var dropZone = this;
            if (document.getElementById('mydropzone').files.length > 0) {
                alert();
                $.each(files, function (index, item) {
                    this.emit('addedfile', 'uploading');
                });
            }

        }
    };
```

now in order to call this function you need to do:

```
Dropzone.options.mydropzone.init();
```